# How do I get the NSDates from a week? Provided I know the weekOfMonth

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I need to know the `NSDate`'s present in a particular week. I know the `weekOfMonth`, `month` and `year`.

For example, if my `weekOfMonth` is 0 and `month` is 2 and the `year` is 2016. I want to get the dates available in the current week (from Sunday to Saturday). But as the first day of this week (Sunday) falls on the previous month, I need to get the dates from 1-Feb-2016 to 6-Feb-2016 (Monday to Saturday).

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comp.month = components.month;
comp.year = components.year;
comp.day = ??; // What should I give here to get the current start date of the week?
```

Or if I could know the start date and end date of the current week, that would be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly clunky approach, based on getting the date using dayOfWeek = 0, and then stepping forward until the resultant date is in the same month

```
int monthTarget = 2;
int dayOfWeekTarget = 0;
int yearTarget = 2016;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp setMonth:monthTarget];
[comp setYear:yearTarget];
[comp setWeekOfMonth:dayOfWeekTarget];

[comp setDay:dayOfWeekTarget];

// see what this gives us
NSDate *firstDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comp];

NSDateComponents *firstDayComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:firstDate];

NSInteger day = [firstDayComponents day];
NSInteger month = [firstDayComponents month];

// move forward if we have to
while (month < monthTarget)
{
    dayOfWeekTarget++;
    [comp setDay:dayOfWeekTarget];

    firstDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comp];

    firstDayComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:firstDate];

    day = [firstDayComponents day];
    month = [firstDayComponents month];
}
```

I'm sure you can tidy this up a bit, but the approach is here!

Comment: Its always gives the same result( 2016-02-01 18:30:00 +0000), no matter what the dayOfWeekTarget is.

Comment: cool - that's what I meant it to do!  I thought you were looking for the first date of the required week that was in the month target?  For the example you give, that would be 2016-02-01